# TDBChart glitch in pie chart when dataset return just one value

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, pie-chart

I create a pie chart using TDBChart and associate a dataset to it, the problem is when the dataset has just one value sides of the pie chart are not there, as soon as more values are added to the graphic it is fine, otherwise it look like the one I attached.

Does anyone now how to fix this issue?[image]

Comment: If there's only one value, then it occupies 100% of the pie. So isn't the above correct?

Comment: I'm talking about the sides of the chart, it should look like a solid pie and and the moment look like more two discs on top. You can see a line in the left side connecting the discs but it should be solid all around. (I hope it make more sense now)